# Is radiation perpendicular in brehmsstrahlung?

Tags: electromagnetism

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) says:

> Bremsstrahlung  is electromagnetic radiation
> produced by the **deceleration** of a charged particle when deflected by
> another charged particle, typically an electron by an atomic nucleus.

[image]

and in this [video](https://youtu.be/h15AJA8a6Ro?t=3) we can see it happening, can you explain why the photon is not emitted in direction ot the tangent but in a normal direction?

Also, can you clarify why they say the particle is decelerated ? isn't it accelerated by the *slingshot effect*? Does the emission take place only once, even though it is deflected all the time?

Note: they claim [here](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0354-7310/2007/0354-73100704100B.pdf) that Tesla discovered it, do you know if it is true?

Comment: Bremsstrahlung has an angular distribution, the image is just a sketch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung and e.g. http://image.slidesharecdn.com/05chap-03productionofx-rays-120423053008-phpapp02/95/05-chap-03-production-of-xrays-17-728.jpg?cb=1335159107. For relativistic electrons the distribution is sharply peaked forward in the direction of the momentum of the electron.

Comment: No and no. Why would you link Tesla to this? Tesla didn't do any serious research into physics.

Comment: The term Bremsstrahlung is more in use for X-Ray production, where charged particles hit a metal target. Synchrotron radiation is more in use for the deflection of charged particles in a magnetic field. It would be interesting, was the sketched situation ever measured? This I'm asking because for the deflection of moving electrons in a magnetic field it is explainable how the radiation happens: https://www.academia.edu/12037987/About_the_internal_cause_of_Lorentz_force_electric_and_magnetic_induction_English_Deutsch_

Comment: The **v** in the Lorentz force formula is a vector and stands for the speed and direction of the moving charge.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler, of course, what has  speed got to do with the magnitude of the B-field, why should it multiply the strength of the field? this is the only instance when v is significant, as I said it is momentum that is usually relevant